# Erlang: First element in a list matching some condition (without evaluating the rest of the elements)

Tags: list, erlang, list-comprehension

As a simple example, suppose I have a list of numbers `L` and I want to find the first element that is greater than some specific number `X`.  I could do this with list comprehensions like this:

```
(mynode@127.0.0.1)24> L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].              
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
(mynode@127.0.0.1)25> X = 2.5.
2.5
(mynode@127.0.0.1)26> [First | _] = [E || E <- L, E > X].  
[3,4,5,6]
(mynode@127.0.0.1)27> First.
3
```

But this seems potentially very inefficient, since the list could be very long and the first match could be early on.  So I'm wondering whether either a) Is there an efficient way to do this that won't evaluate the rest of the elements in the list after the first match is found? or b) When this gets compiled, does Erlang optimize the rest of the comparisons away anyways?

This is how I would achieve what I'm looking for in C:

```
int first_match(int* list, int length_of_list, float x){
    unsigned int i;
    for(i = 0; i < length_of_list, i++){
        if(x > list[i]){ return list[i]; } /* immediate return */
    }
    return 0.0; /* default value */
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

well, something like

```
firstmatch(YourList, Number) -> 
   case lists:dropwhile(fun(X) -> X =< Number end, YourList) of
     [] -> no_solution;
     [X | _] -> X
   end.
```

Comment: Nice.  This is more concise than my solution.  I did have to do a little looking to verify that `dropwhile` does in fact stop evaluating after the first failed match.  I wrapped it up in a function that lets you specify the condition as a function (without having to invert the logic):  https://gist.github.com/3807110

Answer (score 4):

Here's what *I* was able to come up with.  I'd still like to know if there's a better answer and/or if the simplest thing gets optimized (the more I think about it, the more I doubt it).

```
-module(lazy_first).

-export([first/3]).

first(L, Condition, Default) ->
  first(L, [], Condition, Default).

first([E | Rest], Acc, Condition, Default) ->
  case Condition(E) of
    true -> E;
    false -> first(Rest, [E | Acc], Condition, Default)
  end;

first([], _Acc, _Cond, Default) -> Default.
```

Example:

```
14> lazy_first:first([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], fun(E) -> E > 2.5 end, 0.0).
3
15> lazy_first:first([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], fun(E) -> E > 5.5 end, 0.0).
0.0
```

**Edit**

Here's a version without an accumulator.

```
first([E | Rest], Condition, Default) ->
  case Condition(E) of
    true -> E;
    false -> first(Rest, Condition, Default)
  end;

first([], _Cond, Default) -> Default.
```

Comment: Can't address the question of whether there's a built-in shortcut, but this certainly looks like the proper way to roll your own...except your accumulator seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a quick solution:

```
first_greater([],_) -> undefined;
first_greater([H|_], Num) when H > Num -> H;
first_greater([_|T], Num) -> first_greater(T,Num).
```