# How to get value by name with Erlang struct?

Tags: struct, erlang, extract

Newbie of Erlang here.
Have Json like this:

```
{  
"ReadCardResultResult":{  
  "amount":"0",
  "balance":"9400",
  "Status":1,
  "Commands":[  

  ],
  "message":"0000000000000000",
  "ret":{  
     "code":0,
     "desc":"SUCCESS",
     "subReturn":null
  },
  "transactionId":103979,
  "txnInfo":[  
     {  
        "infoId":101,
        "infoName":"TestName1",
        "infoValue":"04432FBAA53080"
     },
     {  
        "infoId":102,
        "infoName":"TestName2",
        "infoValue":""
     },
     {  
        "infoId":103,
        "infoName":"TestName3",
        "infoValue":"9400"
     },
     {  
        "infoId":104,
        "infoName":"TestName4",
        "infoValue":"5"
     }
  ]
}
}
```

My task is to get specific `infoValue` out of `txnInfo` according to `infoName`. For example: I need to get `infoValue` with "TestName3", that would be "9400".

So far I narrowed the Json with `proplists:get_value(<<"txnInfo">>, ReadCardResultResult).` and now I have this:

```
[{struct,[{<<"infoId">>,101},
      {<<"infoName">>,<<"TestName1">>},
      {<<"infoValue">>,<<"043A2FBAA53080">>}]},
{struct,[{<<"infoId">>,108},
      {<<"infoName">>,<<"TestName2">>},
      {<<"infoValue">>,<<"772">>}]},
{struct,[{<<"infoId">>,108},
      {<<"infoName">>,<<"TestName3">>},
      {<<"infoValue">>,<<"772">>}]},
{struct,[{<<"infoId">>,125},
      {<<"infoName">>,<<"TestName4">>},
      {<<"infoValue">>,<<>>}]}]
```

Now, where do I go from here? I'm really stuck on this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That second snippet doesn't seem to be from JSON in the first snippet. The data is different.

Comment: @Dogbert i use mochijson2 and it returnes the second snippet

Comment: Not that. The values were different (and still not all are correct). Anyways, I fixed the `"TestName3"` data and posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To efficiently get the first item of a list matching a predicate, you can invert the predicate and use `lists:dropwhile/2` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12657896/320615) answer for more info about that). Other than that, it's just some pattern matching and a `case` expression:

```
-module(a).
-compile([export_all]).

main() ->
  TxnInfo = [{struct,[{<<"infoId">>,101},
      {<<"infoName">>,<<"TestName1">>},
      {<<"infoValue">>,<<"043A2FBAA53080">>}]},
    {struct,[{<<"infoId">>,108},
      {<<"infoName">>,<<"TestName2">>},
      {<<"infoValue">>,<<"772">>}]},
    {struct,[{<<"infoId">>,108},
      {<<"infoName">>,<<"TestName3">>},
      {<<"infoValue">>,<<"9400">>}]},
    {struct,[{<<"infoId">>,125},
      {<<"infoName">>,<<"TestName4">>},
      {<<"infoValue">>,<<>>}]}],
  WantName = <<"TestName3">>,
  case lists:dropwhile(fun({struct, PropList}) -> proplists:get_value(<<"infoName">>, PropList) /= WantName end, TxnInfo) of
    [] ->
      io:format("no matches~n");
    [{struct, PropList} | _] ->
      io:format("first match: ~p~n", [proplists:get_value(<<"infoValue">>, PropList)])
  end.
```

Output:

```
first match: <<"9400">>
```

If you only care about the first result and want to crash if none is found, you can replace the `case` with just:

```
[{struct, PropList} | _] = lists:dropwhile(...),
```